# Is it possible to pin a local package-repo?

Tags: debian, apt

I bound the folder /var/cache/apt/archives as a local package-source in my system. Is it possible to pin them?

```
$ apt-cache policy | grep archive
500 file:/var/cache/apt/archives/ ./ Packages
```

I think I need a release file. How can I create it? The source is not signed.